# Showing that a r.v. is uncorrelated to a function of two other, mutually independent r.vs.

Tags: expectation, conditional-expectation

Consider three complex random variables, $g$, $x$, and $w$. I know that $g$ and $x$ are mutually independent, $x$ and $w$ are uncorrelated ($\mathbb E[xw^*] = 0$), but nothing about the relation between $g$ and $w$. $x$ and $w$ have zero mean.

I'm having problem showing

$\mathbb E[(g-\mathbb E[g])xw^{*}]=0$.

I usually like to use the law of total expectation to condition on one of the variables, but I can't seem to calculate the resulting conditional expectation. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see what.

One example of where I get stuck is

$\mathbb E[(g-\mathbb E[g])xw^{*}]
=
\mathbb E_g[ \mathbb E[(g-\mathbb E[g])xw^{*}\vert g]]
=
\mathbb E_g[ (g-\mathbb E[g])\mathbb E[xw^{*}\vert g]].$

I don't know how the conditioning on $g$ affects the expectation of the product $xw^*$. No matter how I try to solve it, I end up with the same problem. What am I missing?

**Edit**

Based on Michael's comment, I might have misunderstood something. In the book I'm reading, the following is said:

> - $\mathbb E [w]=\mathbb E [x]=0$
> - $x$ and $w$ are uncorrelated, not necessarily independent
> - $g$ and $x$ are independent
> - No assumption is made in the statistical relation between $g$ and $w$
>
> A direct calculation shows that the second and third terms in 
>   $\mathbb E [g]x + (g-\mathbb E[g])x + w$
>   are mutually uncorrelated, and uncorrelated with $x$.

I'm sorry if I posed the incorrect problem, there must be something I'm not getting.

Comment: What you are trying to show is not generally true.  Are you sure you are working on the correct problem?  Note that $E[E[g]xw^*]=E[g]E[xw^*]=0$ and so your problem reduces to trying to show the (untrue) equality $E[gxw^*]=0$.  You can get a simple counter-example with three zero-mean random variables $A,B,C$ that are pairwise independent, but the three are not mutually independent, and $E[ABC]\neq 0$.

Comment: @Michael, I've added the exact information from the textbook, in case I posted a problem that isn't equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were correct in your original question.  It looks like the book is wrong.  The book seems to be claiming that $(G-E[G])X$ and $W$ are uncorrelated.  To prove that, since both have zero mean, it suffices to show: 
$$ E[(G-E[G])XW]=0 $$
which is what you were trying to show (I am assuming the random variables are real for simplicity).  This reduces to showing $E[GXW]=0$, which is not true in general.

Here is a specific counter-example:

Define $X$ and $G$ as i.i.d. with $P[X=1]=P[X=-1]=1/2$.  Define $W=XG$. Then 
$X, W, G$ are pairwise i.i.d. (for example, compute $P[W=1|X=1]$ and $P[W=1|X=-1]$). 
But $WXG=W^2 = 1$.  So $E[WXG]=1$.

Comment: Yes, what you say makes sense. Thanks for taking your time. I now know why I couldn't prove the claim.